# AngularJS - Send a dom element to the server

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, email, post

Sorry if it is a repeated question but I did not find any solution that suits what I need.

I have a view in AngularJs (with charts and data of a report) and I need to send that same view by email. For this I need to send it to the BackEnd (PHP) and use this DOM element as email content.

I try this

ReportService.js

```
self.sendEmail = function(element) {
   return Restangular.oneUrl('mailer', 'http://localhost/send-email/').post(null,
{
    element: element
});
}
```

Controller.js

```
self.print = function () {

email = document.getElementById('email');
self.reportService.sendEmail(email)
 .then(function(data){
   console.log(data);
 });
}
```

But the server does not receive anything in the POST data

Comment: All the properties of DOM element objects are [non-enumerable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties). As such they are not sent with POST requests.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the html in the element with `innerHtml()`. But it won't meet your requirement as you will not get the necessary styles and js code that is required for your report to be shown. All the styles in the mail content should be online only, otherwise the emai client will not display it properly

Answer (score 0):

You can use Html2Canvas and capture the image of the  html. It is like a screen capture so all your styling will also be captured. But it is not a good idea to get html from client for back end operations.

https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

Edit:

Another approach would be sending the whole html document(with whatever is required) to php with inline styles. the method is shown in the link below.

https://css-tricks.com/sending-nice-html-email-with-php/

Comment: Thanks for your help.

I imagine that by passing it to canvas the functionality of the HTML anchors is lost but is it possible to add this functionality later?

Comment: I am not aware of PHP but you might have to add a link to that using PHP later. Something like an overlay.

But wait a sec...

Why not try this https://css-tricks.com/sending-nice-html-email-with-php/ send the whole html document with inline styles to php and create email like it is shown in the link above.

*Edited the answer*

Comment: I'm going to try it but it needs to be the HTML that is seen in the view since I have some JS executed that shows some charts. In addition, the user can change some data before sending the email.

Comment: Understood. for chart definitely you need to convert them to canvas or image. see if your charting library provides image export which you can send to Backend.